# Custom compile-time versioning scheme and run-time code changes

Tags: c#, .net-core

Based on some requirements I have implemented a custom-versioning scheme to my project. It's a .targets file that's imported into all major project .csproj files in the solution and which uses a number of `<Exec>` commands to gather GIT-related information and calculate the end-version of the generated assembly. This, on its own, works fine. (Yes, I know GitVersion exists, but I couldn't use it...)

However, I've noticed that since implementing this I can no longer make edits after catching a breakpoint. The compiler throws the following error:

```
Error   CS7038  Failed to emit module 'MyModule': Changing the version of an assembly reference is not allowed during debugging: 'MyProject, Version=0.1.0.465, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' changed version to '1.0.0.0'.
```

At face value it makes sense - the versioning information is added during compilation and the .csproj files don't have any version information on their own (so I guess it defaults to 1.0.0.0). The question is - what can I do now? I'd like to keep the versioning scheme which, after all, was a requirement I had to implement. But I'd like to get on-the-fly edits possible for easier debugging...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Save the version to a source file, so that compiler can see it. Where do you save the version now?

Comment: @Dialecticus It's not "saved", as such. The version, once calculated, is just applied via the `<Version>` section in the .targets file itself. How would you recommend saving it?

Comment: In all my VS2017 C# projects there is AssemblyInfo.cs file. In it there are assembly attributes `[assembly: AssemblyVersion(x.x.x.x)]` and `[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion(y.y.y.y)]`. Maybe we are speaking of different things, but when file versions are involved those are the places that I edit to change the version. So, you would have to have this two lines in some .cs file, and rewrite this file whenever the version is recalculated.

Comment: Well, since this is compile-time calculated (and should stay this way), this information cannot be inserted into the typical AssemblyInfo file (that would cause all manner of GIT-related issues, especially since the calculated version is GIT-dependant). But perhaps if the information is injected into a secondary AssemblyInfo file in the obj folder (that's something I've seen being done)...? I'll try that out!

Comment: @Dialecticus I've tried it, dynamically altered AssemblyInfo files at compile time... and it's the same thing, sadly. :(